# PHP get Array with sub Array from SQL

Tags: php, arrays

I am new with coding and I just can't seem to get my head around this. A little help or tip is much appreciated.

Basically I want an array with Questionnaires, which consist of id, name and a sub array of questions. Questions also consist of id and name.(1 Questionnaire can have multiple questions)
Something like this is what I am looking for:

```
[{Questionnaires{id:x, name:x, questions:{id:x, name:x},{id:x2, name:x2}}]
```

This is my query

```
SELECT questionnaires.id QuestionnaireId, questionnaires.title QuestionnaireTitle, questions.id QuestionId, questions.text Question 
FROM questionnaires INNER JOIN questionnaireshasquestions qa ON qa.idQuestionnaire = questionnaires.id 
INNER JOIN questions ON questions.id = qa.idQuestion
```

And my PHP Code:

```
while ($row = $conn->fetch()) {
    
    if (!isset($data['questionnaires'][$row['QuestionnaireId']])) {
        
    $data['questionnaires'][] = array(
            'id' => $row['QuestionnaireId'],
            'title' => $row['QuestionnaireTitle'],
            'questions' => array(
                'id' => $row['QuestionId'],
                'text' => $row['Question']
            )
    ); 
    } else {
        $data['questionnaires'][$row['QuestionnaireId']][] = array(
           'questions' => array(
                'id' => $row['QuestionId'],
                'text' => $row['Question']
                )           
    );  
}
```

The JSON array I get with this is in a wrong/incorrect format:

```
{"questionnaires":[{"id":"1","title":"Are you hungry?","questions":{"id":"1","text":"How is your passion? "}},{"id":"1","title":"Are you hungry?","questions":{"id":"2","text":"Do you drink?"}},{"id":"2","title":"How are you feeling?","questions":{"id":"1","text":"How is your passion? "},"0":{"questions":{"id":"3","text":"Do you like fish?"}}},{"id":"5","title":"Is testing working?","questions":{"id":"4","text":"How is the testing?"}}]
```

As you can see, it repeats the same Questionnaire for each Question within...

I hope I explained well what I am trying to do here :)

Comment: What is the problem, what is not working?

Comment: I updated the question. The format of the JSON array is not what I want... how can I get it in the format I described above?

Comment: "Something like this" -- I don't understand what this is supposed to be. It is neither a PHP array nor a JSON array. For a start, ask yourself what the PHP representation of your data structure should be.

Answer (score 0):

Your collection method was a bit "broken".

This should work:

```
while ($row = $conn->fetch()) {
    $id = $row['QuestionnaireId'];
    if (!isset($data['questionnaires'][$id])) {
        // First time we get this "QuestionnaireId" - 
        // define "container" that collects the related questions.  
        $data['questionnaires'][$id] = [
            'id'        => $row['QuestionnaireId'],
            'title'     => $row['QuestionnaireTitle'],
            'questions' => [],
        ];
    } else {
        // Already got this "container" -
        // put the question into the collection.
        $data['questionnaires'][$id]['questions'][] = [
            'id'   => $row['QuestionId'],
            'text' => $row['Question']
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Super! It get's close. I will try to tweak it. But for now this gives the following result: ```{"questionnaires":{"1":{"id":"1","title":"Are you hungry?","questions":[{"id":"2","text":"Do you drink?"}]},"2":{"id":"2","title":"How are you feeling?","questions":[{"id":"3","text":"Do you like fish?"}]},"5":{"id":"5","title":"Is testing working?","questions":[]}},"status":true,"message":"Succefully got questionnaires!!!"}```
As you can see it doesn't get all the questions, only the last one. And for the last questionnaire it doesn't get the question at all (as their is only one question there)